# Building module based web application in .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modularity

I need to build an MVC application that supports "plug and play" modules. Similar to the way modules in Joomla or Wordpress works. Although I don't need to have any systems in place for managing these, as long as I can install (eg. placing files in a folder on the server) them without publishing the whole site again.

Does anyone have any experience building something like this? Or can recommend an approach to take?

I've looked into [ExtCore](https://github.com/ExtCore/ExtCore) and it does look promising, but I need to check if there are any alternative approaches that should be considered before committing to going down that road.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You can easily build it without using ExtCore, it depends on what level of modularity do you need. IMHO ExtCore tries to modularize too many things. Are you using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I need, at the very least, the ability to replace/update a module without recompiling and publishing the main application. I'm planning on using .net Core, but I can use regular .net if I need to.

Comment: You need the ability to load and unload the assembly during run-time(dynamically). Unloading is currently not supported in .NET core, don't know about full .NET. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19773

Comment: Your main application would be responsible for loading and unloading module assemblies from specific directory possibly during startup. If order/priority of loaded assemblies is important you should implement this as well